# performance problem after adding machinekey in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Does adding a machinekey in the system.web of your web.config cause any performance problems?

I added something like this to my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="aaa"
    decryptionKey="bbb" validation="SHA1" />
</system.web>
```

and now it seems to run quite a bit slower. I am using firebug to see how fast the page is loading.

I ended up with this problem after this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851557/figuring-out-why-asp-net-authentication-ticket-is-expiring/873418#873418)

Note: this is not the actual machine key I am using. I have a proper machine key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, it will not cause a performance problem.

I found out my problem was elsewhere

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution so that other developers can benefit from it?

Comment: My problem wasn't related to this but here it is - one of my queries was taking longer to execute as the database got bigger. I created proper indexes to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Create a proper machine key and see if that works better:

[machineKey generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/keycreator.aspx)

Comment: That's the link I used to create my machine key. I didn't want to post my actual machine key. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" />
```

This is default in ASP.NET 2.0 and there shoud not be any perfomance troubles with these settings